# How to create IntExpr from multiple IntExpr in Java, using OR-Tools, same as in Python

Tags: java, or-tools

In this issue on Github the solution to setting up a constraint requires the user to create a new expression from two expressions
https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/685

like this

```
dur_expr = time_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index) - time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
solver.Add(dur_expr <= max_dur)
```

But trying to do something similat in Java gives the following error

`The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s)com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.IntVar, com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.IntVar`

Any idea how to do this in Java?

I managed to find the documentation on `IntExpr` but could not anything on how to combine the expression

http://google.github.io/or-tools/java/classcom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1constraintsolver_1_1IntExpr.html

What I am trying to achieve is to ensure that the total duration (i.e on-duty time of driver) is not exceeding a time limit.... since there can be a significant waiting time at the first depot node, due to time windows, I cant simply constrain the time dimension to the allowed on-duty time as the slack will exceed the total allowed time.

That is why I wanted to add the following condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.vehicleNumber; ++i) {
    solver.addConstraint(solver.makeLessOrEqual(timeDimension.cumulVar(routing.end(i))-timeDimension.cumulVar(routing.start(i)), onDutyTimeLimit));
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java do not support overloaded operators. You need to use the factory methods on the Solver class.

In your case:

http://google.github.io/or-tools/java/classcom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1constraintsolver_1_1Solver.html#a420d96c79d5d8c45667706d19d1942d9